# Typescript array map vs filter vs?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's a typescript method that wants to walk through an array of strings, and return another array of strings, where, strings that match the regexp (formatted something like "[la la la]" will become just "la la la" and strings that don't match are dropped. So that if my input array is:

```
"[x]", "x", "[y]"
```

it becomes

```
"x", "y"
```

Here's my code:

```
questions(): string[] {
    var regexp = /\[(.*)\]/;
    return this.rawRecords[0].map((value) => {
        console.log(value);
        var match = regexp.exec(value);
        if (match) {
            return match[1];
        }
    });
}
```

I end up with output like this:

```
"x", undefined, "y"
```

because of the "if (match)". What's the right typescript/javascript way of writing this code?

Comment: You could try `.filter(Boolean)` after that to get rid of undefineds.

Answer (score 5):

Just `filter` them out:

```
return this.rawRecords[0].map((value) => {
        console.log(value);
        var match = regexp.exec(value);
        if (match) {
            return match[1];
        }
    });
}).filter(x=>!!x);
```

Comment: What does filter(x=>!!x) do? I see what filter does, but the argument confuses me. The => is creating an anonymous function but why that particular expression works escapes me!

Comment: @pitosalas it's just checking if the value is true. 

x is a value, !x is true if x is empty or false, !!x basically casts the value to a boolean.

!!"" = false
!"" = true
!!!"" = true
!!"not false" = true

Answer (score 1):

What map does is to apply your function to each and every element in your list. Your function does not return any value when regex is not matched. So, probably JS makes it return undefined for that cases. If you wanna drop the ones that do not match regexp, you should use filter right away.

Think about names of functions and you will have a better understanding right away(map maps a function to a list and filter filters a list).

Answer (score 0):

I really believe that sometimes, we try to go way more functional than we should.
What is wrong with this:

```
var regexp = /\[(.*)\]/;
var records = this.rawRecords[0];
var res = [];

for (var i = 0, len = records.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var match = regexp.exec(records[i]);
    if (match) {
        res.push(match[1]);
    }
});

return res;
```

It's not a one-liner, and even if I don't know anything about TypeScript (you also asked about JavaScript in your question), it should also be more efficient than any functional approach.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you... Once I got the semantics of "map" (from Ruby) in my head, I find the one/few liners actually clearer. (And BY THE WAY I am doing the ill advised thing of learning JS while learning TS (actually I knew some js but hadn't written anything more than 2 lines in web apps)

Comment: I agree that it is really clearer a lot of times (I don't use TS but a lot of lodash/underscore). But in the ruby world, what you're trying to do would be calling [compact](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) after a map, which is considered as a sign of wrongly designed code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [reduce() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```
return this.rawRecords[0].reduce((acc, value) => {
    console.log(value);
    var match = regexp.exec(value);
    if (match) {
        acc.push(match[1]);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

please check in [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/marianc/y0rqmfzy/) the result for the equivalent code in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out this problem and shared my result below. Hope this helps. Kindly apologize if I failed or misinterpreted,as I'm new to Typescript.

```
var arr = ["[xy]","x","y"];
var ele =[];
var i;
var op;
var regex = /\[(.*)\]/;
var op1 = arr.filter((element)=>
{
    op =regex.exec(element);
    if(op)
    ele.push(op);
    else{
        ele.push(element);
        console.log(op);
    }
    });
    for(i =0;i<ele.length;i++)
    {
        console.log(ele[i]);
    }
```